# What is the best format to display USA states from a list?

Tags: usability

Should they be abbreviated (Ex. TX, FL)? Or should they be fully spelled out?

Comment: What are we asking here? This isn't a UX question... This should solve your question: http://www.50states.com/abbreviations.htm ?

Comment: @Majo0od, IMHO it's a clear UX question. Many people (US people included) don't know all US states, let alone their abbreviations. Your link doesn't answer the OP question about whether state names should be abbreviated or not, it just says what are the abbreviations for those states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a doubt. What is Ex. TX, FL?

This was a joke but gives you a clear response. Type the full name.

Those two examples you post are easy, but how about MA. Is it MAine, MAssachusets or MAryland... or maybe MichigAn or MinessotA or MontanA.

You could use the two letter abbreviation TX as the value on your database, but not on the list the user is reading.